# Rails 5. How to search in associated models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have 2 models: City and Country. City belongs_to Country, you know how it works.
How to find Country when I'm putting City name into search field?
I know how it works with 1 model

```
@countries = Country.where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%"])
```

but what to do in this case?
I'll be grateful for any useful links or tips, cos I can't find something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@countries = Country.joins(:cities).where("cities.name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
@countries = Country.all.includes(:cities).where("cities.name" => params[:search]).all
```

By the way, it is a bad idea to put search form entry directly into an SQL query as written in your original post as it opens your app up to SQL injection. Read this article here under the header "A1 SQL Injection":

https://blog.codeship.com/preproduction-checklist-for-a-rails-app/